# Open a second form linked to the first form

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2007

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Link new record to existing form](https://superuser.com/questions/313383/link-new-record-to-existing-form)

Could someone please tell me how to link a form?

I enter data on a form, click save, then click a button that opens form2 which is linked to form1.

I'm getting old, I used to do this all the time, but I have forgotten how. the second form is bound to a query.  Do I use a macro or a statment in the query?  I've tried both.

Comment: Huh.. How is this related to your previous question: [How to open a second form based on info from first form?](http://superuser.com/questions/321053/how-to-open-a-second-form-based-on-info-from-first-form) ?

Comment: And what about this one, which also sounds very similar? [Link new record to existing form](http://superuser.com/questions/313383/link-new-record-to-existing-form)

Comment: Agreed, if there is not a reply in a day or so, it may be the way I worded it.